Fail to run/build project - next js
I'hv been doing tutorial from JSMastery about figma and locofy.
The problem is when i try run the project in vscode.
when I try npm start this problem appear:
Error: Could not find a production build in the '.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at setupFsCheck (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\filesystem.js:151:19)
    at async initialize (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:61:23)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:249:36)

I also have search the solution about this problem and most of the answer is by using npm run build/npx next build.
I tried and this happened
Collecting page data  ..D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\@ant-design\icons\es\icons\RightOutlined.js:1
import _objectSpread from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1281:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at mod.require (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at 196 (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\.next\server\pages\index.js:1:37188)
    at t (D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:127)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /
    at D:\Project\realestate\realestate_locofy\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}

I have tried everything but still didnt find the solution

can you share your code link?

Here's the link: https://github.com/WafiyDarwis/realestate_locofy - @kvk30

Firstly build your next js app by using command

npm run build & then start production server using npm start

If you are in development stage use npm run dev to run your next js app.



Can you [edit] your answer and explain how these steps address the question?

Most of the time if next js project fails to run or build its the problem in your existing build of next js project build is saved in .next folder delete that folder and again run npm run build it will recreate the build folder .next and then again try to run it

It seems like an issue with the antd package the project has as dependency.
Try adding the following into your next.config.js and then npm run dev
transpilePackages: [ "antd", "@ant-design", "rc-util", "rc-pagination", "rc-picker", "rc-notification", "rc-tooltip", "rc-tree", "rc-table" ],


thank you, this solve my problem but there's warning said to use menu than overlay.

The first error appears because when you try to run a command like npm run start (which is used to start the server) it is assumed that you have already execuded the command like npm run build (which is used to convert the source files into JavaScript files that will be served). Note that these commands may be different in various Node.js frameworks.
The second error that appears when you try to biuld your source files into a bundle is related to the JavaScript language. In order to use live bindings (see the docs here you have to add a line in the package.json file: "type": "module".
There are plenty of questions on this topic on stackoverflow, like this one. Pay special attention to this answer!
What I'd recommend personally, is to recreate Next.js app using create-next-app and choose typescript: yes in the options. The TypeScript configuration that is generated by "create-next-app" doesn't require you to know the language in depth, and if you're learning a JavaScript framework, it is a very good idea to familiarize yourself with TypeScript.
